# How to adjust height of a DIV with respect to other DIV?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for my school project. It have various nested DIVs. However the size of DIVs are different according to content. I want to make all the DIVs of variable height so that all get the height of the longest one. You can view my page here http://www.risingfaizabad.com/demo/

Please help me.

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097340/how-to-adjust-height-of-column-dependent-on-height-of-another-element/8294476#8294476

Answer (score 1):

You can set absolute positioning of the nested DIV, specifying offsets of its top and bottom points relative to its parent DIV. Note that parent DIV itself must have position:absolute; or position:relative for this to work. The latter (position:relative) is pretty easy and safe

Comment: could you please give me an example. Because when I tried it changes the layout of my page.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery (not CSS only) and assuming all DIVs have a common class to identify just those you care about.

```
$(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('div.commonClass').each( function() {
         var height = $(this).height();
         if (height > maxHeight) maxHeight = height;
    });
    $('div.commonClass').height( maxHeight );
});
```

Or, if you care to simply use a plugin, there is the [equalHeight](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/equal-height) plugin.

```
$(function() {
    $('div.commonClass').equalHeight();
});
```

Comment: I think this will only work when Javascript is enabled. What happens if JS is diabled?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly this is done with [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). But the background images is a bit more complex, so I suspect it wouldn't look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put content left, and content right in a container div, with a background image that is a repeat-y of the left and right column backgrounds. Then just use transparent for content-left and content-right.