# How to Adjust Height of Column Dependent on Height of Another Element?

Tags: css

I have a sort of spacer column on the left and I actually want it to be the same height as the length of the text on that page, which obviously varies greatly from page to page.

This is the CSS:

```
#sidebox {
    width:200px;
    height:2000px;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border:0;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: You're going to have to enclose your left-size column in a parent div or table that grows vertically as text is added to a div/td column on the  right, and make the left-size column element css height: 100%, meaning that it's height is the same as the parent element's height, which grows according to the content of the parent.  You'll may also want to use a min-height on left-side column element.